# Append results from a query to the same result row in PostgreSQL - Redshift

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift

I have a table, with 3 columns A, B , C - where A is not the primary key. We need to select the B, C pairs for each distinct A(group by A), and append the results at the end of the final result set. Is this possible in sql ?

```
A | B | C
a1| b1| c1
a1| b2| c2
a1| b3| c3
a2| b1| c2
a2| b2| c5
```

I need to get

```
a1 | (c1,b1) ; (c2,b2);(c3;b3) 
a2 | (c2,b1) ; (c5,b2)
```

as the rows appended at the end. 
I normally do this via sqlalchemy, and then end up transforming the data in Python, is there a way in which I could do this directly in SQL ?

**EDIT & open question :**
What is the alternative to string_agg() in red shift (Postgres 8.0.2) - more info on use-case above.

On using string_agg I get `ERROR: function string_agg(text, "unknown") does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts`

**Edit 2**: Adding errors using the custom aggregate function

```
An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
CREATE FUNCTION cut_semicolon(text) RETURNS text AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN SUBSTRING($1 FROM 4)

ERROR: unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$$
BEGIN
  RETURN SUBSTRING($1 FROM 4)"
  Position: 53

CREATE FUNCTION cut_semicolon(text) RETURNS text AS $$
                                                    ^

Execution time: 0.24s
(Statement 1 of 7 finished)

0 rows affected
END executed successfully

Execution time: 0.22s
(Statement 2 of 7 finished)

An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' IMMUTABLE

ERROR: unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' IMMUTABLE"
  Position: 1

$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' IMMUTABLE
^

Execution time: 0.22s
(Statement 3 of 7 finished)

An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
CREATE FUNCTION concat_semicolon(text, text) RETURNS text AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN $1 || ' ; ' || $2

ERROR: unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$$
BEGIN
  RETURN $1 || ' ; ' || $2"
  Position: 62

CREATE FUNCTION concat_semicolon(text, text) RETURNS text AS $$
                                                             ^

Execution time: 0.22s
(Statement 4 of 7 finished)

0 rows affected
END executed successfully

Execution time: 0.22s
(Statement 5 of 7 finished)

An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' IMMUTABLE

ERROR: unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' IMMUTABLE"
  Position: 1

$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' IMMUTABLE
^

Execution time: 0.22s
(Statement 6 of 7 finished)

An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
CREATE AGGREGATE concat_semicolon(
  BASETYPE=text,
  SFUNC=concat_semicolon,
  STYPE=text,
  FINALFUNC=cut_semicolon,
  INITCOND=''
)

ERROR: SQL command "CREATE AGGREGATE concat_semicolon(
  BASETYPE=text,
  SFUNC=concat_semicolon,
  STYPE=text,
  FINALFUNC=cut_semicolon,
  INITCOND=''
)" not supported.

Execution time: 0.23s
(Statement 7 of 7 finished)


5 statements failed.
Script execution finished
Total script execution time: 1.55s
```

Also looked through a related answer in Google groups, & **it looks like replacing the separator ";" might help?**  - though I am not sure, which ; to replace in this function definition.
Reference : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sql-workbench/5LHVUXTm3BI

**Edit 3:** 
Perhaps,create function itself is not supported in Redshift ? "ERROR: CREATE FUNCTION is not supported" A 2013 thread says so forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=121137

**Edit 4 :**

```
select A, concat(concat(concat(C, ',' ) , cast(B as varchar)), ',')
from  my_table
group by A,B,C


-- Is it ok to group by all A,B, C - since I can't group by A alone, which removes the related "C" columns-- 

gives -:
a1 c1b1b2b3
a2 c2b1b2
```

But not ALL the entries for C (and with semicolons)

```
a1 c1,b1;c2,b2;c2,b3
a2 c2,b1;c5,b2
```

but I would like the commas in between & also need to know if the group by A, B, C are ok ?

Comment: Any particular reason why you wouldn't want to compute this kind of stuff at the app level after issuing a simple `select A, B, C from table`?

Comment: @Denis Was asked this multiple times at work also.I am using this task as a step into data prep and the last thing I want to do is to do part data prep in redshift - process it in python, join it back in redshift tables, then do rest of data prep. Seems like this will be the best shot ? Also, in Python, when I fetch the records all the "related" records have to fit in memory, which is why my whole data MUST fit -for me to be able to process the related rows to be transformed to SINGLE row(sloppy reason),which kept pushing me to solve it in redshift. I used a dataframe to store A,B & c columns

Comment: I added a lengthier answer yesterday, which explains why you won't be able to do what you're looking for in Redshift. As an aside, don't forget that you can use cursors (and temporary tables) to reduce memory usage when dealing with large sets. And, describing the more complete problem (in a separate question, to avoid making the current answers irrelevant) may very well yield a solution you're not even considering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came to the conclusion that it cant be solved in postgres+ Redshift stack.
This is how I solved it.

```
import pandas as pd
df =pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3],'B':['aaa','bbb','cc','gg','aaa','bbb','cc','gg']})

def f(x):
    return [x['B'].values]

#s=df.groupby('A').apply(f)
series =df.groupby('A').apply(f)
series.name = 'metric'
s=pd.DataFrame(series.reset_index())
print s

   A            metric
0  1  [[aaa, bbb, cc]]
1  2       [[gg, aaa]]
2  3   [[bbb, cc, gg]]
```

Answer (score 2):

### PostgreSQL

```
SELECT
  a,
  STRING_AGG('(' || c || ',' || b || ')', ' ; ')
FROM
  tbl
GROUP BY
  a;
```

**Edit**:
For versions of PostgreSQL before 9.0 (when STRING_AGG was introduced) and even before 8.4 (when ARRAY_AGG was added) you can create your own [custom aggregate function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/interactive/sql-createaggregate.html).

**Edit 2**: For versions before 8.0 (perhaps Amazon Redshift is based on PostgreSQL 7.4 somehow) the $$ syntax is not supported, so the function body needs to be enclosed in quotes, and quotes inside the body need to be escaped.

```
CREATE FUNCTION cut_semicolon(text) RETURNS text AS '
BEGIN
  RETURN SUBSTRING($1 FROM 4);
END;
' LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' IMMUTABLE;


CREATE FUNCTION concat_semicolon(text, text) RETURNS text AS '
BEGIN
  RETURN $1 || '' ; '' || $2;
END;
' LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' IMMUTABLE;

CREATE AGGREGATE concat_semicolon(
  BASETYPE=text,
  SFUNC=concat_semicolon,
  STYPE=text,
  FINALFUNC=cut_semicolon,
  INITCOND=''
);
```

Then use that aggregate instead.

```
SELECT
  a,
  CONCAT_SEMICOLON('(' || c || ',' || b || ')')
FROM
  tbl
GROUP BY
  a;
```

---

### MySQL

```
SELECT
  a,
  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('(', c, ',', b, ')') SEPARATOR ' ; ')
FROM
  tbl
GROUP BY
  a;
```

Comment: I get "ERROR: function string_agg(text, "unknown") does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.
" Do I have to upgrade the Postgres sql for this ?   SELECT version();
version
PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.860

Comment: Asking this since, select string_agg('abc', ':') shows up the same errors as in comment above - so assuming string_agg is not supported, though it is *highlighted*.Another observation : my jar version that is pointed by Redshift is postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc3.jar, why do I then see the version as 8.0.2 as above .

Comment: `STRING_AGG` was added in version 9.0. You definitely have to upgrade your PostgreSQL (if you can). The version you are using - 8.0.2 is extremely old and is no longer supported, it was released on 7 april 2005, **nine years ago**.

Comment: Looks like this was because Amazon redshift does not support it. "Amazon Redshift is based on PostgreSQL 8.0.2. Amazon Redshift and PostgreSQL have a number of very important differences that you must be aware of as you design and develop your data warehouse application" . Also, could you confirm that STRING_AGG is supported in Redshift .Reference, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-features.html - I don't know what operator class STRING_AGG belongs to,l so can't look up in this list.Without this, what are my odds of getting this ?

Comment: So, this means that it doesn't matter that I launch my SQL workbench with 9.0.3, while Redshift  supports 8.0.2. I will not be able to use new operators/agg functions. Also confirmed this from the Redshift's page. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-functions.html . It lists the STRING_AGG() is not supported .

Comment: `STRING_AGG` is an aggregate function. It seems that it is not supported in Amazon RedShift PostgreSQL.

Comment: You can create your own aggregate function via `CREATE AGGREGATE` - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/interactive/sql-createaggregate.html

Comment: I will add it to the answer in a bit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65660/discussion-between-ekta-and-kouber-saparev).

Comment: Added error-log with the new function in Edit2, in my orignal post above . There is something amiss, and I can't seem to get it.

Comment: Ok, maybe Amazon Redshift is based on PostgreSQL 7.4 syntactically, so I edited the answer to support **that old** syntax.

Comment: Perhaps,create function itself is not supported in Redshift ? "ERROR: CREATE FUNCTION is not supported" A 2013 thread says so https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=121137 . Upvoting your comments, but not accepting it, in the hope someone else will. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a very specific reason to do this kind of stuff from within the DB itself, it ought to be done from within your app. Else, you'll end up with sets returning convoluted text fields that you might need to parse for post-processing and so forth.

In other words:

```
select A, B, C from table
```

And then, something like (Ruby):

```
res = {}
rows.each do |row|
  res[row['a']] ||= []
  res[row['a']][] = [row['b'], row['c']]
end
```

If you insist on doing it within Postgres, your options aren't many -- if any at all, in Redshift.

The `array_agg()` and `string_agg()` aggregate functions would both potentially be useful, but they were introduced in 8.4 and 9.0 respectively, and Redshift apparently supports neither.

Insofar as I'm aware, [Redshift doesn't support array constructors](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-features.html), so using the `ARRAY((select ...))` construct, which *might* have worked, flies out the window as well.

Returning something that makes use of the `ROW()` construct is not possible either. Even if it were, it would have been ugly as sin, and impossibly convoluted to manipulate from within Python.

A custom aggregate function seems out of the question if the other answer, and the leads it made you follow, are anything to go by. Which is unsurprising: the docs seem clear that you cannot create a user-defined function, let alone create a pl/language to begin with.

In other words, your only option insofar as I can tell is to do this type of aggregation from within your app. And that, incidentally, is the place where you should be doing this kind of stuff anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably achievable in PostgreSQL. Especially if B and C are of the same type. you may produce two column result and aggregate data in second column using ARRAY, otherwise use JSON. I'm not sure how to produce it in MySQL, but probably there you would need to serialize to string, and invert it in Python.

Either way in my opinion proper answer is: don't do it. You'll get much less readable, hacky, unportable solution, which may not necessarily be a faster one.  There's nothing wrong in some post processing of data in Python to give them final form and in fact it is quite a common practice. Especially if it is purely reformatting output and not used for producing aggregate results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this One to get

```
a1 | (c1,b1) ; (c2,b2);(c3;b3) 
a2 | (c2,b1) ; (c5,b2)
```

This is the code :

1. make temporary table, with running ID, that is example for SQL Server, you can try with another query

   ```
   Select identity(int, 1, 1) as ID, A, '('+C+';'+B+')' as aa
   Into #table2
   From #table
   Order BY A, aa
   ```
2. Make query with Loop

   ```
   Declare @sSql as Varchar(1000), @A as Varchar(2), @A2 as Varchar(2), @aa as Varchar(10)
   Declare @iRec as int, @iL as int
   Set @iRec  = (Select Count(*) From #table2)
   Set @iL = 1
   Set @sSql = ''

   While @iL <= @iRec
   Begin
       Set @A  = (Select A  From #table2 Where ID = @iL)
       Set @aa = (Select aa From #table2 Where ID = @iL)

       if @A = @A2
           Begin
               Set @sSql = Left(@sSql, Len(@sSql)-1)+';'+@aa+'`'
           End
       Else
           BEGIN
               Set @sSql = @sSql + ' Union Select `'+ @A+'`,`'+@aa+'`'
           END

       Set @A2 = @A
       Set @iL = @iL + 1
   End
   Set @sSql = Right(@sSql, Len(@sSql)-7)
   Set @sSql = Replace(@sSql, '`', '''')
   Exec(@sSql)
   ```

is it work ?

Comment: This problem is about getting it to work in Redshift. It doesn't work for me, did it check it in Redshift ?

Comment: i'm sorry, this is just logic. i never use or try Redshift. i'm sorry i can't give you idea